# Parsing HEVC Stream for non IDR frames

Tags: hevc

I parsed the HEVC stream with this code (after converting bytes to hex format)

```
string[] NALunit_string = Regex.Split(fsStringASHex, @"000001|00000001");
```

but after looking at the NAL units types, I can find some with reserved types. Is it normal?

Comment: This depends: What version of the standard text are you using (i.e. in which version were these types declared as reserved types), and what types were these (simply "Reserved" or "Reserved for [...]")? Where did you get the stream, and do you know whether it uses some HEVC extensions (e.g. SHVC)? Finally, how do you parse the NAL unit type from the NAL unit header?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used HM 13.0 to encode my sequence. I convert 2nd to 7th bits to get the NAL type.

Comment: Are the other NAL types reasonable? I.e. do you have NAL types 32, 33 & 34 at the beginning, and later repeatedly NAL types in the ranges [0,9] and/or [16,21]?

Comment: Sorry, then i have no explanation for the reserved types. You could of course check what the HM13.0 decoder does with these NAL units.